# how to make an activity fit to screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

how to make an activity in android studio in which all contents are fit to screen even we run it on smaller screen or bigger screen we don;t need to scroll it on smaller screen?
and also please tell me how to make a button which appears throughout the activity even we scroll the screen the button remains on screen?
i am using android studio 3.2.1 and API 28
so your answer is according to that versions.
Thanks

Comment: Please show the layout you have already tried. It would also be helpful if you would provide a drawing of what you want  to achieve (small and large screen).

Comment: i design a layout for 5.0" screen but i want that when i run this app in 4.0" screen it remains fit on screen i dont need to add scroll view for that

Answer (score 0):

maybe guide lines could help

just double click on the small circle of the guide line and it will work depending on screen size percentage
and don't forget to set image layout width or height to match constraint
[see this gif](https://gfycat.com/SameSpiffyBandicoot)